# programatically access a viewchild inside a method in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a class StudentComponent which extends ParentValidator. The StudentComponent  has many child components within that as addresscomponent ,markcomponent , phonecomponent etc etc....

The ParentValidator is a custom component which gets all the ViewChild in the child class and invokes some validation logic.

So if i include a phonecomponent like this , parentvalidator runs a validation.

```
export class StudentComponent extends ParentValidator {
 @ViewChild('myphone') myphone: MyPhoneComponent;

}
```

Now I have to get addresscomponent inside a method as a viewchild but I dont wanna ParentValidator to run validation on that.I cant change the code of ParentValidator .So How can i access viewchild inside a method without declaring them at the class level? How to programtically get a viewchild?

Comment: If the `ViewChildren` in the base class has a generic selector that you can't modify, I don't think you'll be able to do this.  I'm a bit confused how the derived classes' ViewChildren affect the base class?  Does it use the derived property?

Comment: @chrispy - ran into this the other day. Derived classes still have the original `ViewChild` property set at `ngOnInit`. If you override the property with another `ViewChild` on the derived class, the original `ViewChild` query still gets set, but gets overwritten with the derived `ViewChild`.